# How can I read a sequence of images (im1, im2, ...) from a folder using opencv in Python?

Tags: python

I want to read images named as follow: `image1`, `image2`, `image3`..... `imagen-1`, `imagen` in a folder called "inputfolder". After processing, I want save them in an folder named "outputfolder" as `pimage1`, `pimage2`...... `pimagen-1`, `pimagen`.

How can I do that with python?

i tried this code:

```
 import cv2
 import os
 path_to_folder = "F:\\Nouveau dossier (7)\\Fred_Nat\\RGGchs"
 out_folder = "F:\\Nouveau dossier (7)\\Fred_Nat\\Nouveau dossier (2)"

 f = os.listdir(path_to_folder)

 for i in f:
 path_to_img = path_to_folder + 'image' + str(i)+'.bmp'
 img = cv2.imread(path_to_img)
 cv2.imshow("d",img)

 cv2.imwrite(out_path + 'imagep' + str(i), img)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following where `path_to_folder` is the source folder path and if you wish to save processed images to new folder, write the `out_path. Otherwise, leave the`out_path`same as path_to_folder`

```
path_to_folder = ...
out_folder = ...

f = os.listdir(path_to_folder)

for i in f:
  path_to_img = path_to_folder + '/' + i
  img = cv.imread(path_to_img)
  ... # processing
  cv.imwrite(out_path + '/p' + i, img)
```

Comment: thank you, i tried this code but it is not working so i put the code that i tried in the question above

Comment: you are missing `'\\'`... out_folder should be: `out_folder = "F:\\Nouveau dossier (7)\\Fred_Nat\\Nouveau dossier (2)\\"`